# Powershell command to find access and refresh token time

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

In the past we configured token lifetime for access and refresh tokens but now i would like to find the time line set in the past.

I found PS commands to change the token lifetime but not able to find the command to validate it.

Is there a powershell command which i can run to find the access and refresh tokens lifetime set in Azure AD for the portal and applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you configured the token lifetime with azure ad policy, if so, you could try the command as below, make sure you have installed the [`AzureADPreview`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureADPreview/2.0.2.51) powershell module.

**Sample**:

[`Get-AzureADPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) - Get all the `TokenLifetimePolicy`s in your AAD tenant :

```
Get-AzureADPolicy | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 'TokenLifetimePolicy'} | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]

[`Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipalpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) - Get the policy which has been assigned to the service principal :

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id "<object id of service principal>" | ConvertTo-Json
```

[`Get-AzureADApplicationPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplicationpolicy?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) - Get the policy which has been assigned to the AAD application:

```
Get-AzureADApplicationPolicy -Id "<object id of application>" | ConvertTo-Json
```

For more details, refer to this doc - [**Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Preview)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).